# Push to separate arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

I have a table called products that has a hstore field called data.

So my index looks like this:

```
def index

  @products = Product.all

  @headers = @products.map(&:data).flat_map(&:keys).uniq
  @product_data = []

  @products.each do |product|
    @headers.each do |key|
      @product_data.push(product.data[key])
    end
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json do
      render :json => {
        "myDataAfter" => @product_data.as_json,
        "myDataBefore" => @products
      }
    end
  end
end
```

myDataBefore is basically what I get when I just call the json represontation of the entire product model. It looks like:

```
"myDataBefore":
[
    {
        "id": 76,
        "store_id": 128,
        "created_at": "2014-02-19T04:30:43.455Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-02-19T04:30:43.455Z",
        "data": {
            "81506": "Same",
            "Hello world": "Yes"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 77,
        "store_id": 128,
        "created_at": "2014-02-22T04:39:08.708Z",
        "updated_at": "2014-02-22T04:39:08.708Z",
        "data": {
            "81506": "dasfsdaf",
            "Hello world": "dafs"
        }
    }
]
```

myDataAfter is what my json looks like now, after trying to get what I want:

```
"aaData":["Same","Yes","dasfsdaf","dafs"]
```

So its combining both rows data attributes into one single array. But I really want the "Same" and "Yes" to be in an array, and the "dasfsdaf" and "dafs" to be in another one. So basically each row in the table gets its own array in the JSON. how can I get this?

Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given you have:

```
@products = [{id:76,store_id:128,created_at:"2014-02-19T04:30:43.455Z",updated_at:"2014-02-19T04:30:43.455Z",data:{"81506" => "Same","Hello world" => "Yes"}},{id:77,store_id:128,created_at:"2014-02-22T04:39:08.708Z",updated_at:"2014-02-22T04:39:08.708Z",data:{ "81506" => "dasfsdaf", 'Hello world' => "dafs"}}]
```

You can simply do

```
@products.map{ |product| product[ :data ].values }
# => [["Same", "Yes"], ["dasfsdaf", "dafs"]]
```